# Remove all elements from object except specified key?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object:

```
"languages": {
    "en":["au", "uk"],
    "de":["de"],
    ....
 }
```

How can I remove everything but a specified key, so if I specify 'en' I just want an object that contains "en":["au", "uk"]

Comment: Create a new one containing just the extracted key and values? Use any of a million JS libraries that will reject object keys based on arbitrary criteria?

Comment: So you want to remove all of the keys *except* for `'en'`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply, you could create a new object with specified field;

```
var key = 'en';

var o = {
    "languages": {
        "en": ["au", "uk"],
        "de": ["de"]
    }
}

var res = {}

res[key] = o.languages[key];
```

Comment: The person likely down-voted because it's a workaround, not an answer to the actual question. People who land here are likely looking for the answer as per the title, not the workaround to this unique case.

Comment: This is not an ideal solution. Why? Because in cases where `key` does not exist in the original array, we will create a new array entry with the key and an undefined value. This can be undesirable.

Answer (score 43):

General solution for the original question of 'how do I remove all keys except specified keys' (refined from Rajaprabhu's answer):

```
validKeys = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
userInput = { "a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":4, "e":5 }

Object.keys(userInput).forEach((key) => validKeys.includes(key) || delete userInput[key]);
```

Answer (score 13):

Try to [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) the unwanted properties,

```
var obj = { "languages": { "en":["au", "uk"],"de":["de"] }};

Object.keys(obj.languages).forEach(function(itm){
  if(itm != "en") delete object.languages[itm];
});
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple loop using `delete` will do it.

```
var key = 'en';
for (var k in obj.languages) {
    if (obj.languages.hasOwnProperty(k) && k != key) {
        delete obj.languages[k];
    }
}
```

Comment: The 'key' var should probably be used in the if statement right?

Answer (score 2):

Was searching for the answer and the previous ones helped me, just adding a **functional version of the code** that I needed:

```
function returnNewObjectOnlyValidKeys(obj, validKeys) {
  const newObject = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (validKeys.includes(key)) newObject[key] = obj[key];
  });
  return newObject;
}
```